# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[58], "@react-navigation/native").NavigationContainer')

Tags: typescript, react-native

```
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <NavigationContainer /*onReady={() => SplashScreen.hide()}*/ >
        <Stack />
        <AlertDialog />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
```

I have encountered the error as above, do you have any idea what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have `@react-navigation/native` installed. run `yarn install @react-navigation/native` and make sure you run `pod install` inside ios directory if you are debugging on an iOS device.
If that does not work, try checking this [solution](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10065#issuecomment-1062802873)

Comment: The solution in your link of setting `inlineRequires: false` in `metro.config.js` worked for me.